# Evaluate $\oint_C \frac1{z^3 - 1} \ dz$, where $C$ is the circle $|z + 1| = \frac32$. How is $C$ a circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

> Evaluate $\oint_C \dfrac{1}{z^3 - 1} \ dz$, where $C$ is the circle $|z + 1| = \dfrac{3}{2}$.

I'm confused as to how $|z + 1| = \dfrac{3}{2}$ is a circle in the first place? [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs(z%20%2B%201)%20%3D%203%2F2) certainly doesn't graph it as a circle.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|z+1|=\frac{3}{2} \\
|z-(-1)|=\frac{3}{2}$$

Recall that the modulus $|z-a|$ represents the distance between $z$ and $a$ in the complex plane. Therefore, the equation can be read as "distance between $z$ and $-1$ is equal to $\frac{3}{2}$." which is the definition of a circle with radius $\frac{3}{2}$ and centre $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $z = x + iy$
$$|z+1| = \dfrac 32 \iff |(x+1) + yi| = \dfrac 32 \iff \sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2} = \dfrac  32$$.

Wolfram alpha is graphing $|z+1| = \dfrac32$ where $z \in \Bbb R$.